# Formatting text in a Cell's NoteText

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

From what I can tell the only code I can use to add a string as a Cell's Note Text is Range.NoteText. Is there a way to make part of that NoteText bold? I have the strings saved as values in a Userform and as a public variable.

It is these two lines:

```
Cells(LR, 5).NoteText txtFld6.Value & ": " & modForms.Note1
Cells(LR, 6).NoteText txtFld6.Value & ": " & modForms.Note2
```

I'd like the txtFld6.Value & ": "  portion to be bold since it has the employee ID of the person filling out the form.

This is the full code for that Sub. From what I can tell there are more options for comments so maybe that should be my focus instead, but I just wanted to keep the way it populates as similar as possible to what we are currently doing by hand.

```
'Submit button Subs
Private Sub cmbSubmit_Click()

    Dim LR As Integer
    
    Set modForms.ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Item(modForms.Assay)
    modForms.ws.Activate
    
    LR = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If Cells(LR, 1).Value <> "" Then
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects(modForms.Assay).ListRows.Add
    End If
    
    LR = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    
    Cells(LR, 1).Value = txtRun.Value
    Cells(LR, 2).Value = txtMonth.Value & "/" & txtDay.Value & "/" & txtYear.Value
    Cells(LR, 3).Value = cbInstrument.Value
    Cells(LR, 4).Value = txtSamples.Value
    Cells(LR, 5).Value = cbCT.Value
    Cells(LR, 5).NoteText txtFld6.Value & ": " & modForms.Note1
    Cells(LR, 6).Value = cbNEGEC.Value
    Cells(LR, 6).NoteText txtFld6.Value & ": " & modForms.Note2
    Cells(LR, 7).Value = txtFld1.Value
    Cells(LR, 8).Value = txtFld2.Value
    Cells(LR, 9).Value = txtFld3.Value
    Cells(LR, 10).Value = txtFld4.Value
    Cells(LR, 11).Value = txtFld5.Value
    Cells(LR, 12).Value = txtFld6.Value
    Cells(LR, 13).Value = txtFld7.Value
    Cells(LR, 14).Value = txtFld8.Value
    
    Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: `NoteText` is a method of range object. Don't need `=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try.

```vb
    Dim iLen As Long
    Cells(LR, 5).NoteText txtFld6.Value & ": " & modForms.Note1
    iLen = Len(txtFld6.Value) + 1
    Cells(LR, 5).Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters(1, iLen).Font.Bold = True
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Range.NoteText method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.notetext?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144166)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Comment object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.comment?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm515072)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [Characters object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.characters?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm251072)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm pretty new to VBA and I assumed the comment property wouldn't affect the notetext. It worked though!

Comment: Cell notes have been replaced by range comments. _Microsoft documentation:_

> [Range.NoteText method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.notetext?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144166)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)